# sending the otp via email using Mailgun API

Tags: android, mailgun

I have developed an application which will generate an OTP code and it need to send to the user via email.For this  purpose i planned to use Mailgun 
API.So am i need to send the email in the server side or in the application side?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the API call from both Server and application side, But making the call from **Server side is the usual way** everyone uses because.

- It is more secure.
- Can keep log of API calls easily.

  Where as in the application side there is a bit of security concern. So go for **SERVER SIDE**